The data submitted through registration form in React wasn't inserted into the database and cannot be logged in to the system created with Laravel 11
I was developing registration and login forms for a bookstore app using react, and when I enter data to the registration form and submit it, they are not going to the database which is created using laravel 11 although I implemented APIs. Login is not working as expected.  Below are the react codes.
signup.jsx

  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ email: '', name: '', password: '', confirmPsw: '' });
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({ email: '', name: '', password: '', confirmPsw: '' });

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let errors = {};
    let isValid = true;

    // Checking validations
    if (!formData.email.trim()) {
      errors.email = 'Email address is required';
      isValid = false;
    }

    // Email validation
    const emailPattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if (!emailPattern.test(formData.email.trim())) {
      errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
      isValid = false;
    }

    if (!formData.name.trim()) {
      errors.name = 'User name is required';
      isValid = false;
    }

    if (!formData.password.trim()) {
      errors.password = 'Password is required';
      isValid = false;
    }

    if (formData.password !== formData.confirmPsw) {
      errors.confirmPsw = 'Password does not match';
      isValid = false;
    }

    setFormErrors(errors);
    // perform signup
    if (isValid) {
      console.log('Form submitted:', formData);

      // Redirect to  login page
      navigate('/login'); 
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="text">Book Store</div>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="inputs">
          <h1>Sign Up</h1>

          {/* Email */}
          <div className="input">
            <img src={email_icon} alt="" className="icon" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleInputChange} required />
          </div>
          {formErrors.email && <span className="error">{formErrors.email}</span>}

          {/* User name */}
          <div className="input">
            <img src={user_icon} alt="" className="icon" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="name" value={formData.name} onChange={handleInputChange} required />
          </div>
          {formErrors.name && <span className="error">{formErrors.name}</span>}

          {/* Password */}
          <div className="input">
            <img src={password_icon} alt="" className="icon" />
            <input type={passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'} placeholder="Password" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={handleInputChange} required />
            <button type="button" className="eye-button" onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}>
              <img src={passwordVisible ? eye_slash_icon : eye_icon} alt={passwordVisible ? 'Hide password' : 'Show password'} />
            </button>
          </div>
          {formErrors.password && <span className="error">{formErrors.password}</span>}

        </div>

login.jsx
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; // Allows cookies to be sent with requests


const Login = () => {
  /*password visible or not*/
  
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: '', password: '' });
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({ name: '', password: '' });
  
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible);
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let errors = {};
    let isValid = true;

    //checking validations
    if (!formData.name.trim()) {
      errors.name = 'Username is required';
      isValid = false;
    }

    if (!formData.password.trim()) {
      errors.password = 'Password is required';
      isValid = false;
    }

    setFormErrors(errors);

    if (isValid) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login', formData);
        if (response.data.success) {
          // Redirect to the home page
          return <Link to="/" />
        } else {
          console.log('Invalid username or password');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="header">
        <div className="text">Book Store</div>
      </div>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="inputs">
          <h1>Log In</h1>
          <div className="input">
            <img src={user_icon} alt="" className="icon" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="name" value={formData.name}
              onChange={handleInputChange} required />
            
          </div>
          {formErrors.username && <span className="error">{formErrors.name}</span>}
          <div className="input">
            <img src={password_icon} alt="" className="icon" />
            <input type={passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'} placeholder="Password" name="password" value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange} required />
            <button type="button" className="eye-button" onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}>
              <img src={passwordVisible ? eye_slash_icon : eye_icon}
                alt={passwordVisible ? 'Hide password' : 'Show password'}/>
            </button>

I defined necessary routes, cors middleware and models, controllers and functions. Postman tests are working, but form data is not working as expected. When login clicked,
api.php
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'storeAPI']);
Route::post('/login', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'storeAPI']);

cors.php
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'register'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://192.168.8.101:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With', 'Authorization'],

    'exposed_headers' => [], 

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,


corsmiddleware.php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://192.168.8.101:3000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
        {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }

registeredusercontroller.php
 public function storeAPI(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;
        
        return [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
            'staus' => 201
        ];
}

when login clicked, it shows this error message.
'Failed to load resource: the server responded, http://127.0.0.1:8000/login with a status of 419 (unknown status)'

Since your cros.php accept request with api prefix you should use the prefix on your base URL on your frontend
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'register'],

you can use as follows on your login.jsx
const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', formData);

that will send the request to backend development server. To play with more on this prefix you can edit following configuration on your bootstrap\app.php
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        apiPrefix: 'api/',
        health: '/php',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

For information refer the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#routing-customization
